# Laravel Ajax validation worked [422 Status], but the page did not redirected if validation success and the data already inserted to DB

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, validation

**Laravel Ajax validation worked [422 Status], but the page did not redirected if validation success and the data already inserted to DB**

*There was an error [422 Unprocessable Entity] but i solved as below in code.*

i tried to solve that, it works and redirects successfully without enable ajax validation.

```
    // Routes

        Route::name('authorCreatePost')->get('post/create', 'AuthorController@createPost');
        Route::name('_authorCreatePost')->post('post/create', 'AuthorController@_createPost');
```

```
    // Controller

        public function _createPost(Request $request)
        {
            $validator = $request->validate([
                'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'content' => 'required|min:20',
            ]);
            if (!$validator)
            {
                return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
            } else {
                $post = new Post();
                $post->title = $request['title'];
                $post->content = $request['content'];
                $post->user_id = Auth::id();
                if ($post->save()) {
                    return redirect(route('authorCreatePost'))->with('success', 'Post Created Successfully');
                }
            }

        }
```

```
     // View

         <form action="{{ route('_authorCreatePost') }}" method="POST" id="create-post-form">
            @csrf
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header text-center text-uppercase h4 font-weight-normal bg-light">
                    {{ __('Create Post') }}
                </div>

                @if(Session::has('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">{{ Session::get('success') }}</div>
                @endif

                <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>

                @if ($errors->any())
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title" class="require">{{ __('Title') }}</label>
                                <input id="title" name="title" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="content" class="require">{{ __('Content') }}</label>
                                <textarea id="content" name="content" class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">{{ __('Create') }}</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#create-post-form').submit(function(e){
                    validate_form(e);
                });
                function validate_form(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $("input[name='_token']").val(),
                        }
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ route('_authorCreatePost') }}",
                        method: 'post',
                        data: {
                            _token: $("input[name='_token']").val(),
                            title: $('#title').val(),
                            content: $('#content').val(),
                        },
                        error: function(data){
                            if(data.status == 422) {
                                var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText).errors;
                                $('.alert-danger').empty();
                                $.each(errors, function(key, value){
                                    $('.alert-danger').show();
                                    $('.alert-danger').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');
                                });
                            }
                        },


                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
```

```
[Validation works][1]
[Request and Response for 1][2]
[Here the data valid and inserted to DB][3]
[Request and Response for 3][4]


[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shz0L.png][1]
[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNbO7.png][1]
[3]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6mSn.png][1]
[4]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSr4s.png][1]
```

Comment: in ajax request you can't redirect. you can just return a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just return a success status from your controller

```
response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
```

and then redirect in a success function in your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('_authorCreatePost') }}",
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        //..
    },
    success: function(response){
        window.location.href = "{{ route('authorCreatePost') }}";
    },
    error: function(data){
        //...
    },
});
```

or you can return the route to redirect from your controller

```
response()->json(['redirect' => route('authorCreatePost')], 200);
```

and then redirect to the route in the response on the ajax call success function

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('_authorCreatePost') }}",
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        //..
    },
    success: function(response){
        window.location.href = response.redirect;
    },
    error: function(data){
        //...
    },
});
```

Comment: i tried that before
success: function(response){
        window.location.href = "{{ route('authorCreatePost') }}";
    },

but sorry i missed 'window' in 'window.location.href'.
thanks it works now